# How to find the number of instances of an item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want part of a script I am writing to do something like this.

```
x=0
y=0
list=[["cat","dog","mouse",1],["cat","dog","mouse",2],["cat","dog","mouse",3]]

row=list[y]
item=row[x]
print list.count(item)
```

The problem is that this will print 0 because it isn't searching the individual lists.How can I make it return the total number of instances instead?

Comment: Do not call your variable `list`; this masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search *per sublist*, adding up results per contained list with [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sum(sub.count(item) for sub in lst)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [["cat","dog","mouse",1],["cat","dog","mouse",2],["cat","dog","mouse",3]]
>>> item = 'cat'
>>> sum(sub.count(item) for sub in lst)
3
```

Comment: @Sven: that makes no difference. :-)

Comment: Well, it did fix the syntax highlighting for me (in particular the wrong colour of "sub"), but probably nobody except for me cares. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, the 'sub' name being labelled as a keyword. Subtle, but hardly worth the trouble. :-P

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` is a builtin function for adding up its arguments.

The `x.count(item) for x in list)` is a "generator expression" (similar to a list comprehension) - a handy way to create and manage list objects in python.

```
item_count = sum(x.count(item) for x in list)
```

That should do it

Comment: I think the `x.count(item) for x in list` chunk is a generator expression just to be pedantic.

Comment: @squiguy very true - I'll fix that :)

Comment: A generator expression does not create a list object though; it creates a generator, which is a type of iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [["cat","dog","mouse",1],["cat","dog","mouse",2],["cat","dog","mouse",3]]
>>> count = Counter(item for item in chain.from_iterable(lst) if not isinstance(item, int))
>>> count
Counter({'mouse': 3, 'dog': 3, 'cat': 3})
>>> count['cat']
3
```

I filtered out the `int`s because I didn't see why you had them in the first place.

Comment: If you drop the filter for `int`, you can pass the `chain.from_iterable()` generator *straight* into `Counter()`. Not sure why you filter, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't see why OP had them in there, but thank you for pointing that out for reference :)